# How to make a makefile for lua 5.1.5 on windows or get LuaSocket for lua 5.3.5?

Tags: lua, luasocket

I'm attempting to make a simple server to client communication for fun using lua. The only library i've found able to do this is luasocket, but it's only for lua 5.1, and I cant seem to find any clear instruction as to how to build the makefile for 5.1.5 on windows.

I'm currently using windows 10 and i've looked all over the place, but im brand new to this world and I dont understand what most of what I see means. I've tried following this guide (http://lua-users.org/wiki/BuildingLuaInWindowsForNewbies), but its for lua 5.3 and its makefile.cmd script only supports that version, and fails when trying to use lua 5.1

The error I get while trying to compile it is...

```
F:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1.5\src\*.exe
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
F:\gcc-lua-install\lua-5.1.5\src\*.dll
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
The system cannot find the file specified.

**** BINARY DISTRIBUTION BUILT ****

'F:\gcc-lua-install\lua\bin\lua.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Luajit can be compiled with some newer standard features and 64bit pointers and is far better performing. You can use ffi to call socket functions in C land.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Lua from www.lua.org

[Binaries](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.1.5/

[Sources](https://www.lua.org/ftp/)

https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.1.5.tar.gz

It should also be quite simple to build luasocket for Lua 5.3. There are several resources available online that explain what to do.

Please use websearch for such trivial questions.

Comment: It seems my question was unclear, I was having a lot of trouble getting a makefile to work for it on windows and I couldn't find a clear explanation. I've edited the question to make it a little more coherent.

Comment: @Stratiz a bit unclear? you changed your question to a completely different one. you asked where to find it and now you want to know how to build it. you owe me 5 minutes of my life.

Comment: Are you able to answer my question? If not, I appreciate your time.